# pandas.read_csv() interprets TRUE as boolean, I need a string

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion

I'm reading stock tickers from comma delimited file using pandas.read_csv(). One of the tickers is TRUE, so pandas reader interprets it as a boolean, and fails, since it needs a string to retrieve prices. How can I force TRUE into a string?

Comment: You can try forcing conversion to `str` in `pd.read_csv` via `dtype` parameter, e.g. `df = pd.read_csv('file.cs', dtype={'ticker': str})`.

Comment: That worked wit everything: RAND, INF, TRUE and other stock tickers. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Specify the dtype of the desired column in the `read_csv` method call:

```
pd.read_csv('weirdly_formatted_csv.csv', dtype={'weird_column': str})
```